# Node JS: given a html string, how can I get the content inside of all <script> tags, manipulate and replace it?

Tags: node.js, string, liquid

**Overview**:

I am working on a project that has dozens of `.Liquid` (Shopify) snippets with `<script> tags` inside of them containing JS code.

They're similar to `HTML`, they look something like this:

```
{% assign variable = 'test' %}

<p>hey {{variable}}</p>
<script>console.log("hey")</script>
{% schema %}
{
...json stuff
}
{% endschema %}
```

**Issue**:

Basically what I wanna do is get the content inside `<script>`, manipulate it and replace with the new manipulated one.

I managed to do this using `cheerio`, but it ends up messing up the `Liquid` variables since it doesn't recognize them.

My previous code was looking something like this:

```
let html = cheerio.load(code, { _useHtmlParser2: true });

const { data: js } = html("script").get()[0].children[0];
html("script").get()[0].children[0].data = await minifyJS(js);

const result = html.html();
```

**Expected Behavior**:

I need to:

1. Find all `script tags` in a HTML string;
2. Get the code inside of the `<script>` tag;
3. Manipulate this code (minify, essentially);
4. Replace it with the now minified code.

I am trying to avoid using `regex`, but I can't foresee any other solutions.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like Cheerio is mangling the liquid tags? Maybe try JSDom instead?

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you, it's working almost perfectly! The only issue now is that it's adding quotes to empty data-attributes. So, `<div data-time></div>` becomes `<div data-time=""></div>`. I was fixing this in Cheerio using `htmlparser2` but it doesn't seem possible to use with `jsdom`. Any ideas? Thank you once again for your time and patience!

Answer (score 0):

To get the content inside tags you can use Regular Expressions

```
<script(.|\n)*?<\/script>
```

This is just the regex

```
let str = <Whatever string or data you want to extract script tags>;
let result = let result = str.match(/<script(.|\n)*?<\/script>
/g);

console.log(result);
```

in result you will get the content inside the script tag

Comment: I'd prefer not to use Regex since it opens a massive window for errors, I'd like to use a DOM like Cheerio or JSDom!